# Partial Methods Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-4.1

I am trying to implement partial methods with Entity Framework Code first

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CodeFirstPortalEntity.Models
{
    public partial class ActionItem
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Completed { get; set; }

}
}
```

All i want to do is execute some code when the "Completed "  field is changed

I have been trying to do something like this

```
 partial class ActionItem
{
    partial void OnCompletedChanging(bool value)
    {
        if(value==true)
           {....Do Stuff.....}

    }
}
```

No matter what i do i keep getting

Error   1   No defining declaration found for implementing declaration of partial method 'CodeFirstPortalEntity.Models.Opportunity.OnCompletedChanging(bool)'

I have been reading non stop and have yet to find a solution.  Please help.

Comment: you don't seem to have the signature of the method in the other partial class - can this be the issue? (i.e.` add partial void OnCompletedChanging();`)

Comment: From my reading the On[Property]Changing method is created somewhere else by entity framework.  How does EF know to call this function?